# Jest toHaveBeenNthCalledWith returns the variable value as currently set as opposed to value at time of call

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I am working on a nestjs application using a pretty standard set of nestjs plugins (things like `@nestjs/axios` and `@nestjs/testing`.

I have a fairly simple function that should paginate through API requests and add the resulting values to an array.

```js
async syncRecordList(limit: number = 1000) {
        const url = 'https://my.test.url/records';
        const headers = {
            Authorization: 'Bearer token-value',
        };
        const params = {
            limit, // the per page limit
            offset: 0, // the offset for pagination
        };
        const itemIds: number[] = [];
        let more: boolean = true;
        while (more) {
            const response = await this.httpService.axiosRef.get(url, {
                headers,
                params,
            });
            response.data.items.forEach((item) => {
                itemIds.push(item.id);
            });
            params.offset += limit;
            more = response.data.hasMore;
        }
        return itemIds;
    }
```

To test this simple function, I have the following test:

```js
describe('syncRecordList', () => {
        it('should call multiple times if there is pagination', async () => {
            const response0 = {
                data: {
                    items: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }],
                    hasMore: true,
                },
            };

            const response1 = {
                data: {
                    items: [{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }],
                    hasMore: false,
                },
            };

            const callExpectWith0 = [
                'https://my.test.url/records',
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer token-value',
                    },
                    params: {
                        limit: 2,
                        offset: 0
                    },
                },
            ]

            const callExpectWith1 = [
                'https://my.test.url/records',
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer token-value',
                    },
                    params: {
                        limit: 2,
                        offset: 2
                    },
                },
            ]

            const httpSpy = jest.spyOn(service.httpService.axiosRef, 'get')
                .mockResolvedValueOnce(response0)
                .mockResolvedValueOnce(response1);

            await service.syncRecordList(2);

            expect(httpSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
            expect(httpSpy).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, ...callExpectWith0);
            expect(httpSpy).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, ...callExpectWith1);
        });
    });
```

As you can see from the code, I am expecting the first call to use the params of `limit: 2, offset: 0`, and the second call to use the params of `limit: 2, offset: 2`. The code is designed so that the params value is changed on each call of the loop to modify the offset. This is done before the loop exits, meaning the second time thing, before the `more` value is set to false, we will increment the params offset value in anticipation of another loop.

My expectation is that this would pass. That in the mocks call history it would have the params show two different values. What I actually see however is a failure.

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(n, ...expected)

    n: 1
    Expected: "https://my.test.url/records", {"headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer token-value"}, "params": {"limit": 2, "offset": 0}}
    Received
    ->     1
              "https://my.test.url/records",
            @@ -2,8 +2,8 @@
                "headers": Object {
                  "Authorization": "Bearer token-value",
                },
                "params": Object {
                  "limit": 2,
            -     "offset": 0,
            +     "offset": 4,
                },
              },
           2: "https://my.test.url/records", {"headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer token-value"}, "params": {"limit": 2, "offset": 4}}
```

The result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(httpSpy.mock.calls));` is `[["https://123456789c.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/assemblyItem",{"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer token-value"},"params":{"limit":2,"offset":4}}],["https://123456789c.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/assemblyItem",{"headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer token-value"},"params":{"limit":2,"offset":4}}]]` showing that it things it was called twice with an offset of four.

But it wasn't called with an offset of four, the value of `params` at the end of the test has an offset of four.

If I change the code slightly, to use a copy of params instead of params it works:

```js
    async syncRecordList(type: NetSuiteRecordTypes, integrationId: string, limit: number = 1000) {
        // ... Snipped 
        const params = {
            limit, // the per page limit
            offset: 0, // the offset for pagination
        };
        const itemIds: number[] = [];
        let more: boolean = true;
        while (more) {
            // This was done so that testing would pass. The params object was being modified and
            // causing the tests to fail as it seems to always refer to the variable used, not what what
            // was actually called with.
            const paramsToUse = { ...params };
            const response = await this.httpService.axiosRef.get(url, {
                headers,
                params: paramsToUse,
            });
            response.data.items.forEach((item) => {
                itemIds.push(item.id);
            });
            params.offset += limit;
            more = response.data.hasMore;
        }
        return itemIds;
    }
```

In this case my tests pass as the function is called with what I expected.

In the end my question is, is there a way that Jest called with can actually use what was passed in at the time of calling, not the value of the variable after the test is done?

Comment: Jest isn't going to _copy_ anything here, the problem is that your code does only use a single object (note a [mre] would require far less code, and nothing to do with Nest).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have updated my question to cut out some code to be a minimal reproducible example. There is a one sentence detail that nest is involved, and you are right, it may not have to do with nest.

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/textbook/775bd2409d6f10a31395f072e214bf28) an actual MRE, and it doesn't include Nest.

Comment: _(`sut({ ...payload });` would get the test passing this case, but other examples may be substantially more complicated. See also e.g. [`jestjs/jest#434`](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/434).)_

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for your example and time here. My question was not how to get the test to pass, as I show that I can do that by altering my function to use a copy of the parameters. My question is if it is possible to have Jest actually report what was used at the time of call, instead of the reference. I have used other testing frameworks that function in this way. I am taking from your comments that it is not and that Jest is limited to returning the reference, which if that updates, then you only get the update (and by extension failing tests).

Comment: FWIW [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) stubs do exactly the same. I don't like changing the code just for the tests, but `let offset = 0;` then `params: { limit, offset }` and `offset += limit;` is another option. Or don't mock Axios at all - my preference is to use e.g. [MSW](https://mswjs.io/) to make the test independent of the details of how the request is made.

Comment: The issue you are experiencing seems to be a limitation of Jest. You can try the method suggested in this answer on jest github: https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/4715#issuecomment-339782539

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a limitation of Jest. Comments on issues Jest GitHub issues 434 and 4715 state that copying the value as opposed to using the reference would be too expensive and severely effect the performance of Jest.

Based on the comments to my original question, it seems I had a few choices.

1. Modify my code so that arguments in the loop are always different, rather than references.
2. Modify my test to use a different assert
3. Implement a different library to alter that testing

In the original question I was already doing option 1, but I have refined that based on comments to the question. I ended up with something like this in my method:

```js
async syncRecordList(limit: number = 1000) {
        const url = 'https://my.test.url/records';
        const headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer token-value' };
        const itemIds: number[] = [];
        let offset: number = 0;
        let more: boolean = true;
        while (more) {
            const response = await axios.get(url, {
                headers,
                params: { limit, offset },
            });
            response.data.items.forEach((item) => {
                itemIds.push(item.id);
            });
            offset += limit;
            more = response.data.hasMore;
        }
        return itemIds;
    }
```